# Get default scheduling of loop iterations in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

In OpenMP, when you do not specify any loop iteration policy (in the code pragmas or through environment variable OMP_SCHEDULE), the [specs](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) (section 2.3.2) clearly state that the default loop iteration policy is implementation-defined and implementations may or may not expose it.

Is there a workaround to get this policy ? To be explicit, I would like to get the value of the internal control variable *def-sched-var* defined in the specs.

I am using GCC 4.9 with OpenMP 4.0 on a POWER8 architecture.

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: I am auditing some code that runs (poorly) on a POWER8. The code does not explicitly use scheduling policy and is being run with no OMP_SCHEDULE clause but a strict GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY (use as much as physical cores as possible). The thing is, at some point, increasing the max. number ofthreads (can be done from the application at run time) decrease performance. I am how the threads are scheduled, hence my question.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I never saw any implementation whose default type of scheduling was something else than `static`, but this doesn't mean all of them do use static as default.

However, from your comment, I deduct that you want to establish a correlation between the performance of the code and the type of scheduling that is used.

You have the possibility of running the code with various types of scheduling (namely static, dynamic and guided). This will tell you how the performance varies as a function of the scheduling policy. Maybe this will tell you something right away, but I would try different things, such as looking at every parallel loop and measure its performance. Post the main loops so we can tell you if there is something else going on.

Put simply, I doubt that changing the type of scheduling will solve bad performance that fast.

Comment: Of course trying all scheduling policies would be the right thing to do but I can't do that. For some technical reasons, I cannot stop the application, change the scheduling policy and relaunch it. I just can adjust the max. number of threads it can use and look at the sources.